# How does datatables (jquery table plugin) perform exports to pdf, excel?

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, export, flash, datatables

How does datatables (jquery table plugin) perform exports to pdf, excel without me implementing a server side solution to export the data?
How does  the actionscript /swf mechanism work internally?
The [explanation](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/swf_path.html) in documentation is very brief

Answer (score 0):

It uses a Flash application (the SWF file), and Flash is able to export to files on the client machine.

The documentation on the `File` class in ActionScript is [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html)

Comment: I added a link to the ActionScript documentation.

Comment: What you answered with is not hard to deduce,but Maybe I should be more specific and ask how to read HTML content into a PDF or , xls file using action script...an overview of an implementation that does so...